Was the use of "who" instead of "whom" against the New York Times' house rules?
The online edition of the New York Times had this headline for an article today (emphasis by me):
The Black Blackface Performer Who History Tries to Forget
While the demise of whom has been predicted for more than a century now, all grammar sites I consulted agree that this is a good place to use "whom": History tries to forget him, the unfortunate object, hence the pronoun stand-in can be the objective case whom. In my opinion this would improve the reading flow, clearly marking the leading object as such.
The language-conscious New York Times employs their own manual to ensure correct and consistent language use, the New York Times Manual of Style and Usage, which it also sells as a reference. Its 2015 edition explicitly states:

But in deference to a
grammar-conscious readership [sic! ;-)] and a large classroom circulation, The Times observes the traditional standard:
Use who in the sense of he, she or they ... Use whom in the sense of him, her or them ...

Therefore, I'm wondering: Has The Times abolished that rule? Or is this a simple, rare mistake (I believe it was on the online front page)?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

I've reopened this post because it deserves an actual answer. Please stop giving answers in comments.

The New York Times does not seem to have abandoned the rule, or at least has not stopped using whom in headlines.
Here are some recent examples of headlines that include whom:
12/20/2024 - Trump Moves to Replace Officials Whom New Presidents Traditionally Leave Alone
04/18/2024 - The Artists for Whom It Was Never Too Late
03/12/2024 - To Whom Would You Write an Open Letter?
02/13/2024 - Who Speaks for the President? Depends on Whom You Ask.
01/30/2024 - Megan Thee Stallion and Nicki Minaj: Who’s Mad at Whom?
Mistakes like this may be rare, but they are not unheard of.  The same 2015 article you quote from lists 8 then-recent examples.  I was able to find 6 more examples of this who/whom error from the past year or so.1
It may be worth noting that all of the examples I found use whom where who would have been correct.  This probably reflects my Google abilities more than anything else.  But it also shows that the New York Times has certainly not abandoned the use of whom.


1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6


OMG the "Typos of the New York Times" lawyer is so funny!
